# Cycles rendering objects all black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, render-layers

I added a texture to the bowl, and it came out rendered black. I unwrapped it, and I did a little node editing, to make the plane glossy and B&W. It looks fine in the preview, as well as in material view, and in rendered view, but not in the render.

Another weird part is that Suzanne is also black in the render, even though she just has the default light gray material and no node editing at all. If I render without the bowl, it's just Suzanne in black. I have no idea why this is happening.

Here's my bowl's nodes:
[image: bowl nodes]

And here's rendered view

[image: rendered view]

And here's the render

[image]

[image]

There's definitely a light in the scene.

Comment: Can you post the blend?

Comment: Was it working before you tried to apply the texture to the bowl? You'll have to update your post with  a .blend file.

Comment: @TARDISMaker I never rendered it before I applied the texture so I have no idea lol. And yeah, I'll upload a .blend

Comment: I found the issue, I'll have an answer up in just a few minutes

Comment: Me too, Render Layer mask layer...

Comment: @ToddMcIntosh Yeah, just finished writing an answer on it. Will we be competing to see who comes up with the better answer than? :)

Comment: No, no, no competition, you post your answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think what happened here was just a misclick in your render layer settings. It looks like you accidentally added a layer as a mask layer.

### What is a mask layer

A mask layer is a layer that is used as a mask to turn parts of a renderlayer transparent depending on if anything (that appears in the render) is infront of something from that renderlayer.

### What's the issue?

Your issue, is that you have your first layer (the one that has all your objects on it), set to be a mask layer, so essentially what is happening, is that instead of rendering the objects, there shape is filled with transparency. I just doesn't appear transparent because you don't have film transparent checked.

To fix this, simply uncheck that layer from the mask layers.
[image]

Comment: I had a similar problem, but the issue was that the Material field in RenderLayer had a material in it, pressing the x on it cleared it and there after renders worked.